# Why is this field undefined in Angular2?

Tags: javascript, angular

I have this template in Angular2:

```
<tr *ngFor="#user of users">
    <td>
        <label *ngIf="editing != user.id">{{ user.name }}</label>
        <input #username *ngIf="editing == user.id" value="{{ user.name }}" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <label *ngIf="editing != user.id">{{ user.lastname }}</label>
        <input #lastname *ngIf="editing == user.id" value="{{ user.lastname }}" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <label *ngIf="editing != user.id">{{ user.gender | genderPipe }}</label>
        <select #gender *ngIf="editing == user.id" value="{{ user.gender }}">
            <option value="0">
                {{ 0 | genderPipe }}
            </option>
            <option value="1">
                {{ 1 | genderPipe }}
            </option>
        </select>
    </td>
    <td>
        <img (click)="removeUser(user.id)" width="16px" class="pull-left" src="/images/close.png" />
        <img (click)="editUser(user.id)" *ngIf="editing != user.id" class="pull-left" src="/images/edit.png" />
        <img (click)="saveUser(user.id, username)" *ngIf="editing == user.id" class="pull-left" src="/images/save.png" />
    </td>
```

I set the `#username` attribute to the first input. 
In the `saveUser()`  when I send the `username` parameter, it is `undefined`.

Why is that? how can I fix the problem?

Comment: Because 'name' is already an attribute for inputs? Can you try changing the name to something else like `username` ?

Comment: I have tried, it is the same. Could it be, because it is inside the itaration?

Comment: Obviously psuedocode, but you are using `user.name` and not `username` in `saveUser()` right?

Comment: @Pablo why don't you have `ngModel` for binding?

Comment: But with the ngModel, how can I get the model of the current iteration where the user clicked?

Comment: @Brett DeWoody no, I reading from the param (`username`)

Comment: @Pablo Just send the whole `user` in the `(click)="saveUser(user)"` and in the function grab his `user.id` and `user.name` or `user.username` or whatever

Comment: the value of #username is not inside `user`

Comment: but the `user.name` is, which is the same

Comment: No, if I edit the input, I have the original value of user.name

Comment: that's why you have to use ngModel like @PankajParkar said so it gets updated along with the input value

Comment: Could you add an example, I dont get how to use ngModel inside each iteration of the loop

Comment: Added it as an asnwer for readability, I hope it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `[(ngModel)]` to update value of all property belongs to it instead of using `value` attribute with `{{}}` interpolated value.

**Markup**

```
<tr *ngFor="#user of users">
    <td>
        <label *ngIf="editing != user.id">{{ user.name }}</label>
        <input *ngIf="editing == user.id" [(ngModel)]="user.name" />
    </td>
    .....
    <td>
        .....
        <img (click)="saveUser(user)" *ngIf="editing == user.id" class="pull-left" src="/images/save.png" />
    </td>
```

Comment: user.name in Component, still have the original value of the input.

Comment: I had to set the model like this: `[(ngModel)]`